# Windows 10 - can't log in into user account

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am unable to access my individual account in Windows 10, which is the only administrator account on the computer (there are 2 other non-admin accounts for other family members). I was trying to come up with a way to make W10 stop at the login screen, rather the automatically open the last account, like W7 did. The only way I found to do this was to put a password on my account, for which I included a PIN. I guess that wouldn't have solved to login screen problem anyway. But soon after doing that, in Settings I selected the option under the password setting to not have it ask me for the password. I can't remember the exact wording of what I clicked. I was hoping to just delete the password completely, but the setting I selected was the only option available.

Now on the login screen for my account all that appears below my name is the "Sign-in" box and no place to enter a PIN. Seems perfect, but when I hit enter or click on Sign-in the screen refreshes to say "Enter PIN" with an "OK" button, but no place to enter a PIN. Clicking the OK button just brings me back to this screen. I've tried type my PIN both before and after clicking OK but it doesn't do anything. Is there anything I can do short of reinstalling W10 to be able to regain access to the only admin account on my computer?

Comment: Enable the built-in Administrator user.  You should be able to solve any problems you once you do.  Of course I also will warn you, it sounds you have some system integrity problems, since the interface isn't behaving itself.

Comment: How do I activate the built-in Admim account? I agree that there seems to be something more to this problem.q

Comment: HowToGeek or http://www.tenforums.com are good places to answer that question